# Is there any badges which has not yet been taken?

Tags: discussion

Are there any badges which have not been yet achieved by anyone?

What are/is the most difficult badge to get?

Comment: The [Precognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/892/precognitive) and [Constable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3108/constable) badges are pretty hard to get, not to say impossible.

Comment: @Floern for Stack Overflow  both are completely impossible since the site wasn't on Area 51 and there was no pro-tem mods.

Comment: The "Badges" page states how many times each was awarded https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges. So "Illuminator" and "Sherrif" are the most difficult (but possible) non tag badges from a quick scan down.